# Something strange with my NavBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i have an iPhone app with TabBarController that each tab has a Nav Controller.. one of the Nav Controller pushes to another Viewcontroller. in that View Controller i am trying to Hide the back button and place One of my custom buttons. in the

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self._allUsersParticipantsInTheVideo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self._allUsersInvitesInTheVideo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i < [self._curVideoToShow._videoParticipants count]; i++) {
        [self._allUsersParticipantsInTheVideo addObject:[self._curVideoToShow._videoParticipants objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    for (int i=0; i < [self._curVideoToShow._videoInvitees count]; i++) {
        [self._allUsersInvitesInTheVideo addObject:[self._curVideoToShow._videoInvitees objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [self setNavBar];
}

#pragma mark - Set NavBar

-(void)setNavBar{
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    UIView *navBarItemview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [navBarItemview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // Set cutsom back button
    //UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"];
    UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LeftArrowBg.png"];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 6, backImage.size.width + 4, backImage.size.height);
    UIButton *bttn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [bttn setBackgroundImage:backImage forState:0];
    [bttn setTag:kBackBttn];
    [bttn setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [bttn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 5, 0, 0)];
    [bttn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Bold" size:12.0]];
    [bttn setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [bttn addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [navBarItemview addSubview:bttn];


    UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, 320, 40)];
    [titleLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Bold" size:24.0]];
    [titleLbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [titleLbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [titleLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [titleLbl setTag:kTitleLbl];
    [titleLbl setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
    [titleLbl setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [titleLbl setText:@"All Participants"];

    [navBarItemview addSubview:titleLbl];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navBarItemview;
}
```

As you can see i've written :

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

but on the first time when the app is lunched, i see the back button of the NavBar only for the first time, but later on for every time that i open the app the button remains to be my custom one. ( and also when i Navigate it is my custom )
someone?

Comment: add your code In ViewWillApear not in ViewdidLoad becouse viewdidLoad call only one time at a push but ViewwillApeaer call every time push pop so may be issue is there :)

Comment: Yeh i try this one all ready :(

Comment: from where you have added navcontroller?

Comment: Tab Bar --> Nav View Controller --> View Controller ---> View Controller.. in the last one

Comment: I meant from mainwindow or using delegate or from someviewcontroller??

Comment: @Sosily, Add it in viewDidAppear method and check.

Comment: i try it all ready i think it's ios6 bug!

Answer (score 0):

try with this..

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

or

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

or

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

Comment: some time its not work without assign set method and also backBartButton = nil its work try this..